# Minimum number of dice rolls to get a random permutation

Tags: probability, permutations, algorithms, dice

Suppose that there are $n$ objects, for simplicity labeled 1 to $n$.
You have an unbiased $k$ sided dice.

What is the minimum number of times you need to roll the dice to get an algorithm that samples a uniformly random permutation of $[n] = \{1,2,\dots, n\}$?

For example, if you had a unbiased coin (i.e. 2 sided dice), then to get a random permutation of $[n]$, it is enough to flip the coin $n-1$ times (by arranging 1 to $n$ as the leaves of tree and then flipping coins to see who "wins" among two child nodes. The total number of coin flips here will be $1+2+4+..+\frac{n}{2} = n-1$)

For a $k$ sided dice, my intuition is that using one dice roll you can totally order $x$ numbers such that $x! \leq k$ and $(x+1)! > k$.

So the minimum number of $k$ sided dice rolls needed would be $\sum_{i=0}^{
log_x(n)-1} x^i = \frac{n-1}{x-1}$ using a similar tree structure.

This makes sense to me for when $k$ is a "perfect" factorial (i.e. a factorial of a natural number) since there are no extra numbers on the dice that could come up and when $n$ is a perfect power of $k$. But what about when this doesn't hold?

Edit: Actually, the algorithm above doesn't work but I would still like to know the answer to the original question

Comment: On further investigation, I'm not sure if this is as straighforward as I thought. I found this paper for generations random permutations from coin tosses (https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3009909)

Answer (score 1):

Unless all the prime factors of $n$ are also factors of $k$ there is no finite answer.  With $m$ rolls of the die you have $k^m$ possible results.  You can divide them as evenly as possible into $n$ classes, but there will be a remainder.  You then have to roll again.  If there is more than one possible remainder, you can keep the information of what it is.  For example, let $n=11, k=7$.  One roll doesn't have enough possibilities to tell anything, so you need at least two.  Two rolls gives you $7^2=49$ equiprobable results.  You can assign $44$ of them to the $11$ objects and in those cases you have a selection.  In $5$ of the $49$ cases you don't, so you roll again.  You now have $35$ results, and you can assign $33$ of those to objects.  There are $2$ left over and you roll again.  We can't guarantee success in any given number of rolls, but the probability of failure gets very small quickly.

The reason you can guarantee success if the prime factors of $n$ are also factors of $k$ is that there is some $k^m$ that is divisible by $n$ and the remainder will be $0$.

Comment: Ok so let's say $n$ is a perfect power of $k$. How about now?

Comment: Then you can find $m$ so that $k^m=n$.  Roll a die $m$ times and assign each result to a different object.  If $n$ divides $k^m$ but is not equal, you can assign an equal number of results to each object.  If $n=25, k=10$, you can roll the die twice to get a number from $00$ to $99$.  You can assign $4$ of those to each object.

Comment: I don't think this is right. Suppose $n = 4$ and $k = 2$. You can't generate a generate a random permutation with just 2 coin flips.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the questions as randomly sample one number from $n$ using a $k$ sided dice. What I want instead is get a random permutation of $n$ elements (which has $n!$ choices)

Comment: That doesn't change anything except to replace $n$ with $n!$, the number of permutations.  One of the previous versions of your question seemed to be selecting one object of $n$, but here you are selecting one object of $n!$.  So roll the die $m$ times to get $k^m \ge n!$, divide as many results evenly as you can, and carry over the remainder for another roll.

Comment: Yes but that means this takes $log_k(n!)$ rolls when $n$ is a power of $k$ and $log_k(n!) + O(1)$ rolls otherwise (because you need to reject bad rolls). I don't think this is optimal

Comment: Now if $n=5, k=7$ there are $120$ permutations, so you have to roll three times to get $343$ possibilities.  You can assign $240$ of them to permutations, then carry over the $103$.  Roll again and you have $721$ possibilities, assign $720$ and you have $1$ left.  Repeat as required.  I am not rejecting bad rolls, I am using the information they give.  This is optimal, if complicated.  Maybe your last comment was meant for the other answer.

Comment: So I agree the algorithm works but I'm not sure it's optimal

Comment: Find a better one.  This doesn't throw away any information, like just rejecting bad rolls.

Comment: You are probably right. I think there is no finite upper bound since $n!$ cannot be a power of $k$ (except for the trivial cases of $n,k=2$ or $n!=k$).
But maybe this method might achieve the optimal number of rolls on expectation. I'll have to think some more about this

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to express $n$ in base-$k$.  Then you can express $n$ with $\log_k(n)$ base-$k$ numerals and just roll a $k$-sided die for each numeral.

Obviously, $\log_k(n)$ might not be an integer. In that case, you just round up. Thus the number of dice to roll $d$ is given by:
$$ d = \lceil \log_k(n) \rceil. $$

Then do like so: roll $d$ dice. If the base-$k$ number implied by the rolls is greater than $n$, reject it and reroll all $d$ dice. (That is important; otherwise your sample will not be uniformly drawn.)

After this is done, relabel the remaining numbers in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, decrement the set size to $n-1$, and redo the above. Your best case is you make $\sum_{i=2}^n\lceil\log_k(i)\rceil$ die rolls.

Comment: This throws away the information of what the roll was if it was unacceptable.  The strategy will work, but the average number of rolls is a little higher because of that.

Comment: So I agree this generates a random permutation but I'm not sure it is optimal

Comment: The inefficiency of throwing away die rolls is undesirable; however, conserving the other rolls could lead to the sampling not being uniform. For example, if $n=11$ and $d=10$, we will reject less often if the first die roll is a "1" -- because both "01" and "11" are acceptable numbers while "02" is acceptable but "12" is not.